# How to import images into an Android project?

Tags: java, android, image

I'm using the Kilobolt Android framework. Using a custom Assets class, I'm loading images by using a `BitmapFactory` and reading the actual image from an `InputStream`. Now I'm having problems loading the bitmap from the folder, it keeps giving me an `IOException`.

I tried copying my image file directly to the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder. I don't understand why this isn't working.

My folders look like this:

```
src
 |--main
 |---|--java
 |---|---|--all the fancy java files :D
 |---|--res
 |---|---|--drawable-xxhdpi
 |---|---|---|--fancy images
 |---|---|--other folders and files...
 |---|--other folders and files...
 |--other folders and files...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get a Bitmap from a drawable in a res/drawable-** folder, you should use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(R.drawable.<drawable id>)`

Edit: to get the Resources for decodeResource, you need to have a Context (such as an Activity or a Service), call `getResources()` to get the Resources object

Comment: `decodeResource()` has two overloads and both have a `Resource` parameter. how do i deal with this? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

Comment: Sorry, if you have a Context (such as an Activity or a Service), call getResources to get the Resources object.